# Schedule query in BigQuery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery query which unions two tables (daily Google Analytics exports). What I want is to save the query as a view or table but have that final view/table update automatically everyday as the new Google Analytics data is loaded into BigQuery.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Here's another way using Cloud Scheduler + Cloud Build. **Disclaimer**: I wrote the blog post. https://polleyg.dev/posts/bigquery-scheduler-cloud-build/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Update

[Scheduling recurring queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries) is available now in BigQuery since September 2018

---

BigQuery by itself doesn’t provide any scheduling mechanism.

You can use 3rd party solution or develop your own using client of your choice
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries

For example,

You can use App Engine Cron Service to automate BigQuery query execution
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/features/#cron
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bigquery-api-quickstart

Or, you can use Google Apps Script to script BigQuery query with a Time based trigger to execute that script
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers

Also, check recently introduced  Google Cloud Functions (Beta)
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/

Comment: thanks Mikhail, I'll dig around to find some code examples (struggling at the moment but there must be one ready made somewhere). I've just read that views update automatically every time they are queried. I want to monitor my data in DataStudio so I guess theoretically every time DataStudio report is loaded and connected to a view, it would refresh the data? Worried that might cost a lot but could be a solution.

Comment: If caching is enabled query result in is cached for 12 hours in data studio. There is also an option to refresh report in data studio whenever you want. Therefore you have partial control over data refresh. But we have experienced slight increase in cost when we started using data studio

Comment: Thanks @ShamshadAlam the view works as a temporary fix but it takes a huge amount of time to load in datastudip

Answer (score 12):

**New Feature**: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries

**BigQuery has scheduled queries feature in Beta now.**

[image]

You would need to enable the **BigQuery Data Transfer Service** and the "scheduled queries" is in the BigQuery Transfer Service menu.

Comment: Worth pointing out that this using this "Scheduled Queries" feature in BigQuery ties the schedule/job to the user who created it. So, you need to think about if that person off-boards or using service accounts, which you can't specify in the console. Also, this only allows you to run piece of SQL at a time. Might be ok depending on the use case, but most need to be able to run dependant SQL queries as part of a pipeline.

Comment: Yes. We run into these issues too. 1) we will use a "function" gmail, such as bi_reports@....com to set up the "scheduled queries". This email's purposes is setup the scheduled queries and bigquery transfer etc. so if staff leaving, this email should be handed over. I suggested to Google too, that they should show the creator of the scheduled queries or bigquery transfer, and let people change the creator etc. 2) yes, we still need our pipeline. Google should offer the simple data transfer service pipeline among its services like sql, cloud storage and bigquery. That would be wonderful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53152299/is-it-possible-to-use-service-accounts-to-schedule-queries-in-bigquery-schedule && https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/working-with-transfers#updating_credentials

Answer (score 5):

To add to Mikhail's answer - check out this easy-to-deploy Google sheet:

> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JZkkKcT9yrcYc1g8QqJaIE6PJtoFig3G_ZNbtXuK6fw/edit

1. Copy this sheet.
2. Customize with your query and destination.
3. Run script, ensure permissions are set up right.
4. Schedule an hourly/daily/etc trigger.

[image]

Source: https://twitter.com/anilopez/status/958382085407883264