# bigquery auto update table

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, auto-update

I'm using firebase to collect the app data (one iOS and one Android) and linking to bigquery. so everyday the data will be collected on daily base, but I want everyday's data to be stored in one big table. basically after everyday's data is being collect, I want automatically query insert function to insert the new data(intraday table) into that big table?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a partitioned table
2. Write a script that gets triggered to push the new data into the partitioned table from step 1.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables
[Schedule query in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874629/schedule-query-in-bigquery)

Comment: Is it possible for you to elaborate on the step #2. The link you provided Schedule  query in BigQuery make sense when you need a pooling mechanism for the event. But I am looking for different scenario, I want to get triggered event when any update or data insertion happened in the BigQuery table.