# Step by Step on cronjobs in Bigquery to adjust partitions of a table

Tags: python, replace, cron, google-bigquery, partition

I need to systematically adjust the data in a bigquery table, keeping its partitions, which means that for each partition I will run a query and replace this partition in the bigquery table with the query result. However, I need to do that regularly.

I was wondering if it is possible for me to write a cronjob that will allow me to replace the table partition with its queries results on a daily basis. I know how to replace specific partitions with query results through command line, but I need to implement this on a cron job for it to be ran on a daily basis. If I could do that in Python, it would be awesome!

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: How to build a bigquery cronjob that runs a query and replace the each partition with the query result (to be done daily)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Schedule query in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874629/schedule-query-in-bigquery)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I need to alter an existing bigquery table, and do that in a daily basis, preferrably using python to schedule it. I have zero experience in building a cron job, and would require a step by step on how to build it and test it.