# Dataflow: read from one BigQuery table and write to another

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to run queries to select data from one table in BigQuery and write the data to another BigQuery table. However, I'm running into a typing issue, where BigQueryIO (2.x) says it can't subsequently write the data because the type returned is TypedRead, instead of PCollection

Here's my code:

```
p.apply("ReadCampaignQueries", BigQueryIO.read().from(options.getInputCampaignsTable()))
  .apply("RunQueries", MapElements
    .into(new TypeDescriptor<BigQueryIO.Read>() {})
    .via((TableRow row) -> {
      String query = row.get("eligibilityQuery").toString();
      return BigQueryIO.read().fromQuery(query);
    }))
  .apply("WriteEligibilities", MapElements
    .into(new TypeDescriptor<BigQueryIO.Write>() {})
    .via((BigQueryIO.Read read) -> BigQueryIO.write()
      .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
      .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
      .to(options.getOutputEligibilitiesTable())));
```

Is there any obvious reason why this pipeline wouldn't end up writing the results of queries to the designated table?

It may be worth noting that these reads are happening largely on legacy BigQuery tables, where standard SQL doesn't work yet. But I'm trying to write to a newly created table without this legacy issue.

NOTE: I also tried using readTableRows() instead of read(), but ran into seemingly unresolvable typing errors.

Comment: The part about the legacy tables is a bit confusing. There is no such thing as legacy BigQuery table, standard SQL should work with any table. SQL dialect matters only if you're reading from a view, but even in this case it does not affect results format.

Comment: Also if all you need to do is run a query and write results to a BQ table, you don't need dataflow.

Comment: BigQuery hasn't always supported standard SQL, and our company hasn't migrated many of its tables in BQ to the latest version, enabling standard SQL. There are some syntax differences and a check-box `Use Legacy SQL` that's enabled by default, but sometimes you have to uncheck this to get a query to work.

Comment: If this were a one-off, you're right. We wouldn't need Dataflow, but this is just a part of a larger Dataflow pipeline.

Comment: When I try to run a standard SQL query on many of our tables, I receive this error: `Error: Cannot reference a legacy SQL view in a standard SQL query.`

Comment: That's different - you're trying to query a view that was written in Legacy SQL, not the table directly. So, yes, you'd need to update the view to be also standard SQL if you want to query it using standard sql. I agree with Daria. You still don't need Dataflow in my opinion. Just schedule your queries to read/write.

Comment: If scheduling query works for you, the answer from Mikhail Berlyant for [Schedule query in Bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874629/schedule-query-in-bigquery) might be useful here.