# Can you schedule a BQ query to run daily and save to a table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BQ query that results in a lot of data that I typically save as a new table. Is it possible to schedule this process to happen daily? If it is possible what's the recommended way of doing it?

Comment: also check [Potens.io](https://potensio.zendesk.com) and Magnus in particular - author of BigQuery Mate and Potens.io here

Comment: As Jean-C mentions - I'm marking as duplicate, and adding a reply to the previous post.

Answer (score 0):

Bigquery does not come with it's own job scheduler. You will not be able to do this from the bigquery web view.

You can absolutely do this with a little code. You will have to pick a scheduler to run your bigquery query job at the time you wish. Many just start with a very simple bash script that runs the job via cron.

Another way would be to use apache-airflow as the scheduler and deploy your job as a airflow DAG that would get executed when you want to. Airflow even has a BigqueryOperator that may make this even easier for you.

Basically you will need a little bit of code and the google cloud sdk to do this.

I believe this question might have already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874629/schedule-query-in-bigquery?rq=1)

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874629/schedule-query-in-bigquery/51072091#51072091 :)