# Google BigQuery P4 service account needs iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-build

I am trying to config and run a **BigQuery Transfer Service** from **Google Cloud Build** but I had the following error message.

> BigQuery error in mk operation: P4 service account needs
>   iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken permission. Running the following command may
>   resolve this error: gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding  --member='serviceAccount:service-@gcp-sa-bigquerydatatransfer.iam.gserviceaccount.com' --role='roles/iam.serviceAccountShortTermTokenMinter'

I have tried it using Python library as well as CLI but no luck. I know it can be done via console but I have to do it programatically.

Also I have granted *roles/iam.serviceAccountShortTermTokenMinter* to the bigquerydatatransfer iam service account.

Comment: I have the same problem with Terraform and noticed that the role `iam.serviceAccountShortTermTokenMinter` does not exist. I have also tried with the role `iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator`, as suggested in this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54585291, but it does not work neither in my case. But maybe it will work for you.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to make this work ?